# If f(x) and g(x) are onto , is it possible f(g(x)) or g(f(x)) is not onto

Tags: functions

According to me both should be onto. I think so because g(x) can take any value as it is onto so f(g(x)) for range should like f(x) and hence should be onto. Could you tell wbere I am wrong and give an example as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141670/how-to-prove-that-the-composition-of-two-surjective-functions-is-surjective

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that the composition of two surjective functions is surjective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141670/how-to-prove-that-the-composition-of-two-surjective-functions-is-surjective)

Comment: I mean to say that there are various proofs of the statement "the composition of two surjective (onto) functions is surjective" on this site.

Comment: ok thanks a lot